# Polynomial Regression: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). but there are no Infinite or Nan values

Tags: python, numpy, sklearn-pandas

I am Using Sklearn and I'm getting an Error...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('Noodles Data.csv')
d = {'Pack': 1, 'Bowl': 2,'Cup': 3, 'Tray': 4, 'Can' : 5, 'Box': 6}
df['Style'] = df['Style'].map(d)

X = df.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.iloc[:, 3].values.reshape(-1,1)

poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 6)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
poly_reg.fit(X_poly, y)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y)
```

After This, I'm getting the following Error...

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I've tried all possible ways to remove NaN values from my data but still couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Where can I find `Noodles Data.csv`?

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the compete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.